# TS Error: es2015, Type 'Array<any> | undefined[]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: typescript

When I change tsConfig.json target: es5 from es2015. I started getting build error as

error TS2488: Type 'Array | undefined[]' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

```js
 this.navItems = [
      ...(this.authService.hasHomePageAccess() ? { displayName: 'Home', iconName: '', route: 'home' } : []),
      ...(this.authService.hasAboutPageAccess() ? { displayName: 'About', iconName: '', route: 'about' } : []),
      ...(this.authService.hasReportsPageAccess() ? { displayName: 'Dashbaord', iconName: '', route: 'dashbaord' } : []),
    ];
```

Any suggestion would be great!

Comment: `{ displayName: 'Home', iconName: '', route: 'home' }` and the other two objects are not iterable. More generally, you should most likely go with a simple `if` and `push` for conditionally adding items.

Comment: This was working fine in es5, not sure what have changed in es2015.

Comment: uhm if your tests are true, you return an object, otherwise an empty array... this is not consistent.. both returns should be identicals. either objects or array. spreading a value that us either an object or an array is wrong